# Define bar colors of matplotlib's barh based on dataframe column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I want to plot my table as a histogram using matplotlib's `barh` function. The table is a pandas dataframe with structure:

[image]

`test` is the independent variable and `count` is the dependent variable. I want the bars to be different colors for the different `species` (blue, green, orange, etc) so I tried the code

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'test': np.linspace(1,16,16).astype(int),
                        'count': np.random.randint(30,120,16),
                        'species': ['species 1','species 1','species 1','species 2','species 1','species 1','species 2','species 2','species 1','species 2','species 2','species 2','species 1','species 1','species 1','species 1']
                       }
                 )

plt.figure(figsize=(14,6))
plt.barh(data=df, y='test', width='count')
# plt.barh(data=df, y='test', width='count', color='species', color_map={'species 1':'b', 'species 2':'g'})
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.ylabel('test number')

plt.show()
```

But I can only get the bars to be one color:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make species the index of the dataframe, then use `.loc` to graph the species separately. I also added a legend, but feel free to remove it:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'test': np.linspace(1,16,16).astype(int),
                        'count': np.random.randint(30,120,16),
                        'species': ['species 1','species 1','species 1','species 2','species 1','species 1','species 2','species 2','species 1','species 2','species 2','species 2','species 1','species 1','species 1','species 1']
                       }
                 )

# Set the index to species
df.set_index('species', inplace=True)

# Seperately graph the species
plt.barh(data=df.loc['species 1'], y='test', width='count', label='species 1')
plt.barh(data=df.loc['species 2'], y='test', width='count', label='species 2')

# Add a legend to the graph
plt.legend()

# plt.barh(data=df, y='test', width='count', color='species', color_map={'species 1':'b', 'species 2':'g'})
plt.xlabel('frequency')
plt.ylabel('test number')

plt.show()
```

This resulted in the following graph:
[image]